# Orientation change in Android using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

```
document.addEventListener("orientationChanged", updateOrientation);
```

I am trying to call a function on `updateOrientation`, but the function is just not called. I am using javascript code for the same.

Can anyone help me with `orientationChange` using javascript code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the event name is `orientationChange`, why do you have `orientationChanged` in your code?

Comment: Actualy, all letters in event name should be lower case

Comment: @Dan that's not true: camelCase is always allowed to have a code more readable by humans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so easy: I played around it a lot too :) 

First you might have noticed that some android devices (for example samsung galaxy tab) will be detected as portrait while they are landscape and viceversa. So first you need to build functions to detect the orientation based on screen.width and screen.height if ipad is not detected (ipad will always show the orientation correctly .. I'm not a fun of it anyway).

Then you have to fire the callback function after a while that the orientation change is detected with a timeout to let the whole environment change accordingly to the new orientation.

So here is how I do .. happy to share it :)

```
function orientation_changed ()
{
    if ( is_portrait() )
    {
        //do something
    }
    else if ( is_landscape() )
    {
        // do something else
    }
    clearTimeout(window.t);
    delete window.t;
}

window.t = undefined;
window.onorientationchange = function (event)
{
    window.t = setTimeout('orientation_changed();', 250);
}

function is_landscape()
{
    var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if ( uagent.search('ipad') > -1 )
    {
        var r = ( window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90 );
    }
    else
    {
        var r = ( screen.width > screen.height );
    }
    return r;
}

function is_portrait()
{
    var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if ( uagent.search('ipad') > -1 )
    {
        var r = ( window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180 );
    }
    else
    {
        var r = ( screen.width < screen.height );
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I am running Android 2.2 on T-Mobile Galaxy S and landscape/portrait detection is switched.

Comment: @Zorayr yes on Galaxy they are switched. The above script should fix it (I tested it on a Galaxy S Tab), if you mean they still are switched using the above script, try to use a longer timeout by changing 250 in a bigger number. Hope it helps

Comment: If using `onresive` event, you won't wait for 250 miliseconds

Comment: @Dan the timeout is needed to ensure that the properties of window and screen are updated by all devices. Events are detected before those are updated on many old android devices. No difference for the purpose of the question in using onorientationchange event or onresize event.

Answer (score 0):

To test native "orientationchange" support, use `"orientationchange" in window`

As a fallback, use `onresize` event and check `window.outerHeight > window.outerWidth`

Comment: The OP already knows about those events: he/she asked for some working snippet.