# CSS mobile - portrait orientation after fullscreen

Tags: html, css, mobile, fullscreen, landscape-portrait

I have a website for mobile devices. I have problem with portrait/landscape when returning back from full-screen mode.

1. I have device in landscape mode.
2. I go to a page which triggers browser full-screen mode.
3. Now when I click on some link and got redirected on other page, full-screen is disabled. That's correct.
4. However, now when I switch to portrait mode, website acts like in landscape mode. Computed width is the same value as in landscape mode. This happens only after return from full-screen mode.

My content div has set `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `max-width` to `100%`. This specifies the width should never be more than `100%`

`width` only sets the initial value, it does not re-calculate every time the screen size changes

Comment: Not helping... browser somehow thinks that 100% = 640px which is device landscape width.

Comment: Mmmmm....... You could use Javascript to re-calculate 100%? Or do you want to do this in pure CSS? If so, I am not sure how to solve this.....

Comment: You could try looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236920/mobile-site-reset-the-viewport-on-orientation-change) question

Comment: setting it via javascript helped, thanks. However I still dunno why I have to do that explicitly after return from full-screen mode.

Comment: I am not sure either. You may be able to add a `<meta>` tag to solve the problem without JS.

Answer (score 0):

Setting width explicitly after orientation changed helped.

```
$(window).on("orientationchange", function (e) {

    $(".page-content").width(screen.width);
});
```