# viewBox of SVG is not display correctly after Orientation is changed

Tags: javascript, svg

I use the code below to display some graphics with SVG. All work's fine after loading the page in portrait or landscape modus. But when the orientation is changing the viewBox is not displayed correctly. For example when load the page in portrait modus and change the orientation to landscape it will cut some circles and zooms the viewBox not correct. What I do wrong?

```js
viewPort.setAttribute("width", screen.width);
viewPort.setAttribute("height", screen.height);
viewPort.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 "+(screen.width)+" "+(screen.height));

document.getElementById("header").style.width = screen.width;

document.getElementById("div1").style.width = window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById("div1").style.height = window.innerHeight;
document.getElementById("div1").style.minWidth = window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById("div1").style.maxWidth = window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById("div1").style.minHeight = window.innerHeight;
document.getElementById("div1").style.maxHeight = window.innerHeight;

document.getElementById("div2").style.width = screen.width;
document.getElementById("div2").style.height = screen.height;
document.getElementById("div2").style.minWidth = screen.width;
document.getElementById("div2").style.maxWidth = screen.width;
document.getElementById("div2").style.minHeight = screen.height;
document.getElementById("div2").style.maxHeight = screen.height;

function drawCircle(x) {
  var c = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');
  c.setAttribute('cx', x);
  c.setAttribute('cy', 50);
  c.setAttribute('r', 20);
  circle.appendChild(c);
}
var x = 50;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  drawCircle(x);
  x = x + 50;
}
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          #header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: blue;
          }
          #div1 {
            position: relative;
            overflow: auto;
            background-color: red;
            width: 100%;
            height: 0;
            left: 0; right: 0;
            top: 0; bottom: 0;
            min-width: 0;
            min-height: 0;
            max-width: 0;
            max-height: 0;
          }
          #div2 {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width: 100%;
            height: 0;
            left: 0; right: 0;
            top: 0; bottom: 0;
            min-width: 0;
            min-height: 0;
            max-width: 0;
            max-height: 0;
          }
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="header">
        <div id="div1">
          <div id="div2">
            <svg id="viewPort" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 0 0" preserveAspectRatio="none">
              <svg id="circle"></svg>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is reloading the page after reorientation an option? It's likely `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` not being update correctly

Comment: or try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17987838/6860684)

Comment: Reloading can be a option but without clearing the "content" of the data. I read a few about it but not sure how should this work with AJAX exactly.